# Access 2013 web app site actions menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

I'm new to SharePoint so please excuse me if this question has been asked before.

I've created a Access 2013 web app and loaded it to my SharePoint 365 site. Everything is working as expected but I have a small problem I'm trying to resolve. I need to hide the Site Actions (gear icon) menu shown below and/or prevent all users except admin users from downloading the app to MS Access.

[image: Site Actions Menu]

I know I can lock the app before uploading it to a site and the menu won't show any longer, but if I do that, I no longer have access to the DB connection string which I need as I've built a custom admin and reporting tool which connects to the DB.

So, if I can lock the app and still get access to the connection string, that would be ideal, but failing that, if I can somehow hide the actions menu, I'm happy with that as well. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution that works for me. Not sure if it's the correct solution but hey...it's doing what I want.

I ended up keeping the app unlocked so that I had access to the connection string but hid the gear icon from users with some CSS.

I added a custom CSS file with the following lines:

```
.ms-siteactions-root {display: none !important;}
```

This overrides the inline CSS for the gear icon and hides it from the user. In my Site Settings - Site Master Page Settings menu I then specified this CSS file as my Alternative CSS file and reset all sub-sites to use the new CSS file.

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

Thanks